# What could be the reason NextJS Image's won't render on iOS 16 if they are not initially visible?

Tags: javascript, image, next.js, safari, lazy-loading

I decided to use NextJS for faster routing & image optimization. Unfortunately, some images won't load properly on iOS devices. I have a scrollable horizontal container with Product Images.

Some of the images fall outside the visible area, therefore you need to scroll to see them.

On the web, it works without an issue. But when I test it on my iPhone (iOS 16)'s Safari browser, I noticed the images outside the visible area are not rendered at all. Let me show what I mean.

How it should be (Chrome Device Tool):

[image]

How it actually is on iOS 16:

[image]

Weird thing is, if I rotate my phone, it actually renders images.

I am using the Image/Next component with priority and unoptimized props set true. I've tried with and without both, but nothing changed.

I am using the latest NextJS for the front end. No other libraries at all. Backend is an express server but it only provides image pathways etc. The server is Nginx with reverse proxy.

Here is the React code:

```
import styles from "../styles/ProductItem.module.css";
import priceFormat from "../Helpers/priceFormat";
import Image from "next/image";
import Percentage from "./icons/Percentage";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

function ProductItem(props) {
  const router = useRouter();

  let marginStyle = {};

  if (props.noLeftMargin) marginStyle.marginLeft = 0;
  if (props.noRightMargin) marginStyle.marginRight = 0;

  return (
    <div
      className={`${styles.itemContainer} ${props.className}`}
      style={marginStyle}
      onClick={() => router.push("/product/" + props.data.id)}
    >
      <div className={styles.imageContainer}>
        <Image
          className={styles.productImg}
          src={props.data.imgSmall}
          width={160}
          height={160}
          alt={props.data.name}
          priority={true}
          unoptimized={true}
        />
        {props.data.salePercentage > 0 && (
          <div className={styles.percentageContainer}>
            <Percentage className={styles.percentageSvg} />
            <div className={styles.percentageOffText}>
              {`%${props.data.salePercentage}`}
              <br />
              OFF
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className={styles.priceLabel}>
        {props.data.salePercentage
          ? `$${priceFormat(
              props.data.price * ((100 - props.data.salePercentage) / 100)
            )}`
          : `$${priceFormat(props.data.price)}`}
      </div>
      {props.data.salePercentage > 0 && (
        <div className={styles.oldPrice}>{`$${priceFormat(
          props.data.price
        )}`}</div>
      )}
      <div className={styles.productName}>
        {props.data.brand} {props.data.name}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductItem;
```

Here is the `{data}` provided via props:

```
{
    id: "ca629a01-7c58-49f1-949e-fad574c28b3e",
    imgLarge: "/images/products/electronics_smartphone_1.jpg",
    imgSmall: "/images/products/electronics_smartphone_1_small.jpg",
    brand: "Chip",
    options: [
      {
        name: "Storage",
        values: ["64GB", "128GB", "256GB"],
        affectsPrice: 1,
      },
      {
        name: "Color",
        values: ["black", "white", "gray", "red", "gold", "silver"],
        affectsPrice: 0,
      },
    ],
    name: "Smartphone",
    price: 684,
    salePercentage: 0,
    saleReason: "",
    viewCount: 10438,
    soldCount: 4706,
    maincategory: "electronics",
    rating: "3.60",
    warranty: 2,
    availableColors: ["silver", "gold", "red", "white"],
    subcategory: "electronics_smartphone",
    sellers: [....]
}
```

You can test my app here: [Ertuway.com](https://ertuway.com/)

Comment: Try to zoom out a bit on your mobile Safari (for example, set the zoom to 90%), and then reload your page. By zooming out, you'll effectively tell your browser that the width is different (larger), and some of the `@media` in your CSS will not be triggered, while others will. The reason I'm suggesting this - you mentioned that rotating your phone fixes the images not showing.

Comment: Zooming out and resizing both cause Safari to render the missing images. I suspect it has has to do with NextJS not rendering images outside the viewport. I guess I will implement my own lazy-loading method.

Answer (score 3):

If you wrap the Image/Next within a container and if you give **`filter:drop-shadow`** effect to the container element, for some weird reason, Safari browsers won't render the images properly. Simply remove the **`filter: drop-shadow`** and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Remove any modification on `overflow-x` on `body,html,#__next` elements (or any parent elements).

I dont know what was happening, but I suspect that Apple did something in the last iOS update that caused this. (As the same site was working fine before.)

Anyway, removing `overflow-x: clip` from said elements fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

This image issue is resolved after I added `width`; you can also try it, like this:

```html
<Image src={logo} alt="logo" height={200} width={200} />
```